# Merge multiple columns into one column in pyspark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input DataFrame:

```
id,page,location,trlmonth
1,mobile,chn,08/2018
2,product,mdu,09/2018
3,product,mdu,09/2018
4,mobile,chn,08/2018
5,book,delhi,10/2018
7,music,ban,11/2018
```

Output DataFrame:

```
userdetail,count
mobile-chn-08/2018,2
product-mdu-09/2018,2
book-delhi-10/2018,1
music-ban-11/2018,1
```

I tried merging single column into one but how to merge multiple columns into one?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = (df
  .groupby("id")
  .agg(F.concat_ws("-", F.sort_array(F.collect_list("product"))).alias("products"))
  .groupby("products")
  .agg(F.count("id")).alias("count"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just groupby userdetail columns and get count. Try this,

```
>>> df.orderBy('trlmonth').groupby('page','location','trlmonth').count().select(F.concat_ws('-','page','location','trlmonth').alias('user_detail'),'count').show()
+-------------------+-----+
|        user_detail|count|
+-------------------+-----+
| mobile-chn-08/2018|    2|
|product-mdu-09/2018|    2|
| book-delhi-10/2018|    1|
|  music-ban-11/2018|    1|
+-------------------+-----+
```